# When running my program, nothing is shown in the console

Tags: java

```
public class quartz {

    public static void main (String[] args) {
        int i = 0;
        int sum = 0;
        int[] n1 = {54, 40, 37, 64, 81, 15, 65, 72, 61, 57, 83, 3, 67, 12, 30, 54, 11, 51, 3, 78, 48, 31, 68, 77, 64, 68, 95, 68, 35, 82, 57, 26, 67, 41, 47, 80, 36, 88, 5, 9, 55, 87, 77, 8, 65, 31, 7, 79, 49, 22, 32, 94, 34, 12, 20, 30, 91, 12, 57, 77, 37, 96, 22, 29, 17, 76, 36, 56, 80, 33, 20, 65, 57, 40, 50, 97, 20, 92, 25, 14, 19, 84, 12, 62, 20, 42, 99, 52, 88, 29, 75, 48, 27, 73, 46, 72, 48, 84, 19, 55};
        while (i < n1.length)
            sum += n1[i];
        i = 0;
        System.out.println("Sum: " + sum + ".");
        System.out.println("Average: " + (sum/n1.length) + ".");

        double[] NE = {-0.6179074665219488, 0.012080423982449795, -0.21346000509541063, 0.08299652983289585, 2.44401680106775, 4.902778859313734, 1.7132831483350532, -4.2004763396051725, -4.043856195861675, -2.6728507023602326, 5.181911533071974, -2.1235877432845354, 7.603895698367564, -5.6730748575837975, -3.5868701412258464, 8.50824673494424, 1.9530312960520657, 1.4057711751329447, -6.6010520166956885, -0.8889270825881894, -3.066437913144831, -1.047977711607209, -0.6183425325427638, -1.9567474971238643, -1.6108985491087715, -3.4762343504063105, -0.7819967483948718, 1.2787199500848474, -1.724036624119682, 4.134045084705252, -4.302090407212001, 4.522452909896921, -9.510982189042458, 4.483571903648103, 4.734972592935479, 1.3007048393668028, -1.5733757395516363, -1.9343054344201707, 6.787212280236046, -0.35603892339489995, -1.3414921239899753, -0.9393551256779856, -1.9298884254368263, 6.043295105337908, 2.9330671137121733, 2.8561036619044047, -0.8293767467550212, 6.123622142714353, -2.2350961485598777, 7.20722805161423, 5.515389689089437, -2.7666432567169745, -4.344590134196103, 3.3453531590362613, 10.413288779778698, 0.3986583788822756, 1.8156402784897105, -6.495232639280744, -2.5586148068696852, 2.456750085945401, -2.0241915465317994, 2.6640207424833706, -3.221638093253812, -0.13291701098446618, 4.525894152095317, 3.833943185257407, -2.892260297173234, -3.247865929061468, 6.129696012756685, 4.451839001858698, -3.142375819178058, -1.0758596832313212, -7.85705595464708, -3.376343621066232, -3.993944532318441, 13.146850947670861, -1.3900676627648902, 3.8600378751921256, 3.9652071948870447, -2.4382860496298324, 3.0864605092488304, -10.769089293963074, 1.9773754511588617, 4.826841112732377, 7.9219782116860324, -3.266132871461332, 1.8118819669439024, 0.698579723806034, 7.119629551067371, -0.9141128559070014, 1.5143207368301361, -8.587596597534729, -0.9387144566983379, 2.5641381148921805, 10.628593146418485, 3.794317923770138, 6.2802756227726615, -0.05171930511667566, 0.8736426098894451, 0.6226851580000003};
        double[] NW = {9.631212195521316, -2.1235831279282698, 3.7468670477204773, -4.559878135521824, 3.2444286767576545, 6.2877828741148605, 6.520597627024687, 2.642307472836288, 1.2002893113069557, 0.32620641006622675, -3.368962812990781, -2.588868228199504, 4.356518441561512, -0.5955112302723241, 0.3875648501871751, -2.9311051175998064, 2.0095554763173666, -1.228769483871199, 5.900445902470515, 0.41527619439744434, 2.9752128071432145, 4.805920315662717, -4.797853823364673, 5.752192282393844, 2.9073605365834556, 2.4870719041084497, -1.7994046436584152, 7.79554996548367, 4.4174973514255536, 2.084039895979635, 0.6281302992116424, -3.1466915662704524, 3.646400672147826, 0.9609952887592054, -6.070082172976056, -0.9392599054917704, 0.904301836858967, 5.926867039519574, 3.238559698585232, -4.439332575192746, 1.352444182896236, -0.24594080100384297, -1.6395807550351367, 3.591208179788307, 4.15757174804611, -3.5334824535956173, 0.5302366137985215, 9.564674975899017, 4.175389023096817, -0.9827335882191762, 4.305890552392608, 3.059083687714633, 2.3224548745551488, 0.1934380213592375, 1.0235814, 1.1716370685853148, -2.931711339626567, -4.214035402157694, -1.0093422753964358, -4.843082160061708, -7.148710177896536, -1.910725804980465, -0.22905523068711164, 3.8200222938181367, -1.744095856344644, 1.354958988184811, 0.9933832752568843, 0.8820951391051288, -2.062035935350486, -7.633897329029599, 0.49911238393151325, -1.1684033502541722, 4.090099097765502, 4.566828839384462, 0.6901115935421007, -4.30695891725898, -5.637531096381548, 2.6920329212478507, -1.522395621132775, 6.351734133984433, 0.4895678835360122, -4.755548841958967, -2.826990702897114, 1.974618789378563, -6.999938959339396, 0.6289774718852977, 3.2732671487606266, -1.2781272997669557, 6.725303989648547, -7.163688015215646, 5.547683884070125, -3.0189942298996213, -0.2487963910538069, -0.46314538549764894, 5.3913279138183645, -4.018219623545416, 6.491084381355617, -1.5629014732514819, -6.557894883162792, -3.856421007612216};
        int sumEeven = 0, sumEodd = 0, sumWeven = 0, sumWodd = 0;
        while (i < 99) {
            sumEeven += NE[i];
            sumEodd += NE[i+1];
            i += 2;
        }
        i = 0;
        while (i < 99) {
            sumWeven += NW[i];
            sumWodd += NW[i+1];
            i += 2;
        }
        System.out.println("Front coordinates:");
        System.out.println("Latitude: " + sumEeven + "  Longitude: " + sumEodd);
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Back coordinates:");
        System.out.println("Latitude: " + sumWeven + "  Longitude: " + sumWodd);
    }
}
```

This code has no errors, and runs, but the console is empty. I have my run configurations set up correctly, so not sure what the issue is. I also made sure that my console was linked to this project and not another, and it is.

I'm running Eclipse Neon if that changes anything.

Some info about the project, although seemingly irrelevant:

n1 calculates the sum of that array of ints and then take the average of the sum

NE and NW calculate the sum of the even parts of each array and the odd parts of each array, and adds each up individually, and they end up being latitudinal and longitudinal coordinates.

Comment: `while (i < n1.length)
            sum += n1[i];`  youre are not incrementing `i` therefore infinite loop

Comment: there is also an error at   int sumEeven = 0, sumEodd = 0, sumWeven = 0, sumWodd = 0;
        while (i < 99) {
            sumEeven += NE[i];
            sumEodd += NE[i+1];
            i += 2;
        }
subEeven should be double because the array element is a double

Comment: And that caused a seg fault. Good eye.

Comment: @jobethbillien yes that's something I needed to fix. When I said it had no errors, I meant no syntactical errors, but thanks for catching that as well :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your program will never leave this loop what are you trying to do here:

```
while (i < n1.length)
            sum += n1[i];


0 < n1.lenth  it's always true
```

try this and see

```
 while (i < n1.length){
            sum += n1[i];
            i++;
 }
```

Comment: Yes, I realize now that was my error (thanks to the first comment on my post). Thank you though, makes sense now as to why nothing was showing in the console.

Comment: learn who to use debug  in eclipse than you can know where you program has stoped and what are the value of variable. see a video on youtube it's recommended if you want to be a good programmer ^^

Comment: Will do. I just switched to java in eclipse (from using gcc in terminal for c), still getting the hang of things. Thanks for the tip though.